# "word-wrap: break-word" with inline block children

Tags: css

I have a div with mixed `display: inline` and `display: inline-block` elements, and I'm trying to get it long lines to wrap properly when the parent has a `word-wrap: break-word` applied.

So for example if I have

```
<div><span>hihihi</span><span style='display: inline-block'>hello</span>moremoremore</div>
```

I would like the text wrapping to behave as `word-wrap: break-word` normally does, and break where needed. What I am getting instead is a break right after the `inline-block` element. Is there any way to change this behavior?

I set up a minimal example in a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEXdMR

To see what I want, just comment out `display: inline-block` in the styling for the `<b>`.

Comment: Why `inline-block` and not just use an inline element?

Comment: This is a simplified example, I need to be able to set both width and height and have margins on the element in my actual use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `white-space: pre` in your parent `div`

```
div
{
  margin: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre;
 }
```

Here's an updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByLYgv

As per documentation, taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

> **pre**
>
> Sequences of whitespace are preserved, lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at <br> elements.

Comment: This doesn't work: it doesn't wrap at all. white-space:pre disables all wrapping. The word-wrap property says _how_ to wrap but does not enable wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the property `display: contents;` to `<span>`. It works for me.